# Anaconda Navigator gets killed automatically on opening

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda Navigator on my Windows 10 PC. But, when I try to open Anaconda Navigator, it shows the green icon which says `Initializing` and then `Adding featured channels` and later disappears completely. It ceases to be listed in the Task Manager as well (apparently getting killed automatically)

Furthermore, when I access it using `anaconda-navigator` command, it does not display any error.

here is my `conda info`:

```
active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\user\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\user\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.1
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\user\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.1 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you downloaded from https://docs.anaconda.com?
It's a heavy weighted application. It runs smoothly in 8GB RAM configured system

Comment: yes, I have downloaded it from the website itself, but my system has 4GB RAM

Comment: thank you, I uninstalled a software which was taking up a lot of RAM in the background, now it's working :)

Comment: After installation it'll download 9-10gb of libraries and packages itself. This is the main issue with your system.